# Join with multiple rows and i am getting multiple results

Tags: sql

I have two tables with thousands of records, I tried different ways to join the tables but it is not working.

I  tried to join on code (table1) = code (table2) and modifier (table1) = modifier(table2) where service from (table1) between effective and term (table2).

I either get one the match for codes with modifier or multiple incorrect results.
Can anybody provide some advice?

Please see the following tables:

```
    TABLE ONE                   
CLAIM # LINE SEQ    SERVICES FROM   SERVICE TO  CODE    Modifier    AMOUNT
LA123456    1   3/1/2015    3/3/2015    99213       $15.00
LA123456    2   3/1/2015    3/3/2015    73030   26  $5.00
LA123458    1   10/1/215    10/1/2015   73030   TC  $30.00
MS123456    1   7/1/2015    7/1/2015    73030       $45.00
MS356911    1   9/6/2014    9/10/2014   80305   53  $10.00
MS894015    1   6/30/2014   6/30/2014   80305       $20.00

TABLE               
CODE    MODIFIER    EFFECTIVE   TERM    AMOUNT
99213       1/1/2015    12/31/2015  $10.00
99213       1/1/2014    12/31/2014  $9.00
73030       1/1/2014    6/30/2014   $18.00
73030       1/1/2015    6/30/2015   $20.00
73030   26  1/1/2014    6/30/2014   $3.00
73030   26  1/1/2015    6/30/2015   $4.00
73030   TC  1/1/2014    6/30/2014   $19.00
73030   TC  1/1/2015    6/30/2015   $20.00
73030       7/1/2015    12/31/2015  $21.00
73030   26  7/1/2015    12/31/2015  $18.00
73030   TC  7/1/2015    12/31/2015  $19.00
80305       1/1/2014    12/31/2014  $10.00
80305       1/1/2015    12/31/2015  $12.00
80305   53  1/1/2014    12/31/2014  $5.00
80305   53  1/1/2015    12/31/2015  $6.00
```

Comment: Please post your SQL and table structure, and tag rdbms you are using.

Comment: what is your desire result? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: inner join is not working :my total records are 42575 lines; when i did the inner join ; the results is 37024.

Answer (score 0):

select t1.*,t2.* from table1 t1 inner joint table t2 on t1.code = t2.code and t1.Modifier = t2.Modifier where t1.SERVICESFROM >= 'Date' and t2.EFFECTIVE <= 'Date'

Answer (score 0):

The last line depends on your business rules.

```
select *
from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.code = b.code
and isnull(a.modifier,'') = isnull(b.modifier,'')
and a.[services from] between b.[effective] and b.[term]
```